# Swipe to Refresher remove Circle indicator

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I have a specific situation. My client requested to remove a circle indicator from swipe to refresher library because i added a default android toast that is telling user that data is loading when he scroll bottom to load more data. I'm currently using this library for layout:
https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout

Does anyone have idea how can i remove that circle that is spinning when I'm pulling fingers from bottom of the screen. I manage to do it partially with setrefreshing(false). It won't load on middle of the screen while loading but it's still visible when user is pulling from bottom.

This is the circle that I'm talking about:

[image: img]

Comment: Have you made a Github issue on that library asking this question?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not to use third party `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Android already provided it in support v4.

you can use it like

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.swiperefreshlayouttest.MainActivity"
>

<!-- Other Views-->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and when you user swipe from top it will visible.

Code for Java

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

override method for that

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

This all you want.

Comment: problem is that default swipe to refresh library does not support swipe from bottom right?

Comment: Yeah thats not supported. You can use this instead https://bitbucket.org/andreyice/swiperefreshlayoutbottom

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [`SwipRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) from the design support lib
2. Use [`setRefreshing(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean)) to hide the indicator

Comment: problem is that default swipe to refresh library does not support swipe from bottom right?